# making filters in a class

Tags: c++, filter

I am making a program that saves multiple records in a file. I have different classes representing different records and another class, a template class that manages the file.

```
template <class DataType> class Table
{
public:
    Table(const char* path);
    bool add(const DataType& reg);
    template <class FilterType> void print(const FilterType& filter) const
    {
        DataType reg;
        ...

        if (reg == filter)
        {
            cout << reg << endl;
        }

        ...
    }


private:
    const char* path;
};

class Student
{
public:
    char cods[5];
    char noms[20];
};

class Course
{
public:
    char codc[5];
    char nomc[20];
};

class Rating
{
public:
    char cods[5];
    char codc[5];
    int prom;
}
```

I have to print the ratings for one student, and all the students in a course. Something like this:

```
Table<Rating> trat("path.dat");
trat.print("A001") //print the ratings for student A001.
trat.print("C001") //print the students for course C001.
```

All help would be much appreciated.

------Edit-------

Ok, Thank you for answer. I use cstrings becouse I need a fix size for each member on the classes, becouse I going to write those classes to files.

What I want to acomplish is to make a template class table that works with any type or record.

What I have been thinking was that I can use operator overloading for compare, and output.

Something likethis:

```
class Student
{
public:
    char cods[5];
    char noms[25];

    class CodsType
    {
    public:
        CodsType(const string& cods) : cods(cods) {}
        operator string() const { return cods; }
        string cods;
    };
};

class Course
{
public:
    char codc[5];
    char nomc[20];

    class CodcType
    {
    public:
        CodcType(const string& codc) : codc(codc) {}
        operator string() const { return codc; }
        string codc;
    };

};

class Rating
{
public:
    char cods[5];
    char codc[5];
    int prom;

    bool operator==(const Course::CodcType& codc) const
    {
        return (this->codc == string(codc));
    }
    bool operator==(const Student::CodsType& cods) const
    {
        return (this->cods == string(cods));
    }
};
```

And then:

```
Table<Rating> trat("path.dat");
trat.print(Student::CodsType("A001")) //print the ratings for student A001.
trat.print(Course::CodcType("C001")) //print the students for course C001.
```

But the problem is that i have to do a class for each filter. There is a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, from your code (even from the edited version), i don't have a single clue, what are you trying to filter, or what this "Table" class does, and what "cods", "codc" and "noms" want to mean. So I, (and probably others too) have no idea, what to tell you, other that giving a few pointers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all "What are you trying to do" ?

Templates are powerful and others, but they won't thik on their own. You still need to understand what are you trying to do.

FIRST: you are programming in C++. Do NOT use char arrays. Use std::string. In most case that's what you want, some "text".

```
#include <string>    

class Student
{
public:
    std::string cods;
    std::string noms;
};
```

SECOND: what do you mean by `reg == filter` ??? reg and filter has different types! they can not be equal! If you want to compare them you need to define what "equal" means.

Templates won't help you. They are not a magic wand. You need to THINK on your own. And you do NOT need templates if you're using it for only one type.

```
#include <string>

class Table
{
  Table(const std::string & path);
  bool add(const Student & a);  // add student to table
  bool add(const Course & a);   // add course to table
  bool add(const Rating & a);   // add rating to table
  void filter(const std::string & str) const; // filter by string and print
};

void Table::filter(const std::string & str)
{
  // find students, courses, and ratings here
}
```

You still need to figure out how do you want to handle these 3 structures. That's still up to you